# Flutter firestore listen is interrupting by previous page firestore listen

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am developing an app with firestore. In my app main screen i am calling firestore listener in `initState()`. when i am going next screen (Screen B) then the previous screen (main screen) `initState()` function
executing  and interrupting listeners in screen B. I am not calling main screen initState() in Screen B.
Why it showing ?
Below shown as the code.

```
   class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
    MainScreen({Key key}): super(key: key);

    //The title want to My App
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new MaterialApp(
            title: 'My App',
            home: MyMainPage(title: 'MyApp',));
    }
    }

    class MyMainPage extends StatefulWidget {
    MyMainPage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
    final String title;


    @override
    _MyMainPageState createState() => new _MyMainPageState();
    }


    class _MyMainPageState extends State<MyMainPage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
    _MyMainPageState();

        @override
    void initState(){
        super.initState();

        loadData();

    }

    loadData(){

        widget.authentication.getFirestore().collection("xxx").document("xxx").collection("xxx")
        .snapshots().listen((data){
                debugPrint("Entered in _loadData firebase fn in MainScreen");
        });
    }

        @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new  new Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            appBar: new AppBar(
            iconTheme: IconThemeData(
                color: Colors.black, //change font color here
            ),
            ),
            body:new RaisedButton(child:new Text("click),onPressed: () {redirectToScreenB();})

    }

    redirectToScreenB(
            Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ScreenB()));
            //I have used no change found
            //  Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ScreenB()),ModalRoute.withName('/'));

    )


    }
```

code for ScreenB

```
    class ScreenB extends StatefulWidget {
        ScreenBage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
        final String title;
        @override
        ScreenBPageState createState() => new ScreenBPageState();
    }


    class ScreenBPageState extends State<ScreenB> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
    ScreenBPageState();

        @override
    void initState(){
        super.initState();
        debugPrint("Screen B initState");

        loadSecondData();

    }

        loadSecondData(){

            debugPrint("loadSecondData started");

            widget.authentication.getFirestore().collection("xxx").document("uid")
.collection("data").where("name", isEqualTo:"xxxx")
        .snapshots().listen((data){
                debugPrint("Entered in loadSecondData firebase fn in ScreenB");
        });
    }
```

The out put is coming when going to ScreenB

Screen B initState
loadSecondData started
Entered in _loadData firebase fn in MainScreen

And the `loadSecondData()` is stoping . Why the previous page listener is loading in new page.
I have tried `StreamBuilder` but not `loadSecondData()` without interrupt.

Comment: When you call `snapshots().listen(...)`, you start listening to the stream of data from a collection. When you leave the first screen, you need to stop listening to that stream by unsubscribing from it. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51918047/stop-listening-to-snapshot-updates-in-cloud-firestore-in-flutter

Comment: I have used 'streamSub.cancel();' but it is not stopping. I added that in dispose() method. not working.

Comment: Did you check if the dispose method is called? There might be a better lifecycle event to do this in, such as `deactivate`, although I admit I've never done this myself and have a hard time parsing the Flutter docs for these methods: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/State/dispose.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are loading the same data in screenB from screenA.

Your code is the same for both `loadData()` and `loadSecondData()`. You should change one of them.

**loadData()**

```
{
widget.authentication.getFirestore().collection("xxx").document("xxx").collection("xxx").snapshots().listen((data) {
    debugPrint("Entered in _loadData firebase fn in MainScreen");
});}
```

**loadSecondData()**

```
{
debugPrint("loadSecondData started");
widget.authentication.getFirestore().collection("xxx").document("xxx").collection("xxx").snapshots().listen((data){
debugPrint("Entered in _loadData firebase fn in MainScreen");
});
```

Comment: I have changed the code. I am using two different collections. Not same.